# Interchanging differentiation and expectation

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, dirac-delta

I have a nonnegative random variable $X$ with $E[X] < \infty$, that admits a density wrt to the Lebesgue measure. For arbitrary $K > 0$, I write

$$P(K) = E[\max(X-K,0)]$$
I am interested in the function $K \mapsto P(K)$. My first question is

> Under what conditions is $P$ twice differentiable?

My second question is assuming that it exists,

> What is $\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial K^2}$?

With some handwaving I can "show" that $\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial K^2} = f_{X}(K)$ where $f_X(K)$ is the density of $X$ evaluated at $K$. I reason as follows.

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial K^2} &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{P(K+h) - 2P(K) + P(K-h)}{h^2} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{E[\max(X-(K+h),0) - 2\max(X-K,0) + \max(X-(K-h),0)]}{h^2}\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}E\left[\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\max(X-(K+h),0) - 2\max(X-K),0) + \max(X-(K-h),0)}{h^2}\right]\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}E\left[\delta_{K}(X)\right]\\
&\stackrel{(3)}{=}f_X(K)
\end{align}
$\delta_K(X) := \delta(X-K)$ denotes the Dirac delta function above.

Things that require justification (as far as I can tell) are the numbered equalities above.

$(1)$ is clear. Some kind of dominated convergence must be invoked here. I did not think about this step in depth to be honest.

$(2)$ is bizarre, to say the least, but my reasoning is there is that the function inside the limit is an isosceles triangle with base $2h$ and height $1/h$ for every $h > 0$. It always integrates to $1$ and is zero outside the interval$[K-h,K+h]$. So as $h \to 0$ it "should" converge to the Dirac delta function in some sense.

$(3)$ is probably justified. Since $X$ admits a density,
$$E\left[\delta_{K}(X)\right] = \int\delta_{K}(x)f_X(x)dx = f_X(K)$$
I see no issue here but I am not absolutely certain either.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could give me hints/pointers as to what needs to be done to make all the arguments here fully precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be the CDF of $X$. Then
$$
P(K)=\mathbb{E}\left(X-K\right)^+=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(x-K\right)^+{\rm d}\mu=\int_K^{\infty}\left(x-K\right){\rm d}\mu=\int_K^{\infty}x{\rm d}\mu-K\left(1-\mu(K)\right),
$$
or more clearly,
$$
P(K)=K\mu(K)+\mathbb{E}X-K-e(K),
$$
where
$$
e(K)=\int_0^Kx{\rm d}\mu,
$$
and obviously, $e(\infty)=\mathbb{E}X$.

Thanks to this result, if $\mu$ yields a PDF $f$, i.e., ${\rm d}\mu(x)=f(x){\rm d}x$, then
$$
P'(K)=\mu(K)+Kf(K)-1-Kf(K)=\mu(K)-1,
$$
and thus
$$
P''(K)=f(K).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity $\int_{k}^x1\,dt=x-k$, then change the order of integration:
$$
\begin{align}
P(k)
&=\int_{k}^\infty (x-k)f_X(x)\,dx
\\&=\int_{k}^\infty\left(\int_{k}^x1\,dt\right)\,f_X(x)\,dx
\\&=\int_k^\infty\int_t^\infty f_X(x)\,dx\,dt
\\&=\int_k^\infty \mathbb P(X\ge t)\,dt=\int_k^\infty1-F_X(t)\,dt
\end{align}
$$
Now, using the fundamental theorem of calculus, $P'(k)=-(1-F_X(k))$, and using the fact $X$ has a density $f_X=F_X'$, $P''(k)=f_X(k)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Calculon: My pleasure. Good luck to you :-)